# How to run React js or Node js (server script) with bun runtime

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, mern, bun

when i am trying to give this command 
**Node js**
**$bun App.js** 
*error: Cannot find module "./util.inspect" from "/Users/rehan/taptechinc/server/node_modules/object-inspect/index.js"*

**React js**
what command can i write ?

Comment: it looks like bun does not support all the npm packages just yet. I've got this same error with `nano` npm package or axios (which I believe could be part of the react app).

Answer (score 0):

> bun run app.js

or for react (for example)

> bun create react sample-app 
> cd sample-app 
> bun dev